# How to convert coordinates from one Spherical system to another rotated by 90 degrees without going to Cartesian

Tags: math, geometry, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation, spherical-coordinate

I need to convert a set of points from one spherical system to another rotated by 90 along the axis in the equatorial plane. I want to rotate the points in this system, then return them to the previous one.I do not want to use the Cartesian system as an intermediary, so can this be done without leaving the conception of spherical coordinates? The image shows the same point in different spherical coordinates, are there any conversion formulas for this case?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding/substracting π/2 to the appropriate coordinate does what you want if I understand what you're asking correctly.

Comment: This will only work when rotating along the main axis.Unfortunately you cannot rotate along any longitude in this way. This will only lead to contraction of coordinates to the poles

Comment: Ah ok I see. Isn't the rotation caracterized by its coordinate in the original base? Adding/substracting the coordinate of the rotation to the coordinate of the point would give the new coordinates. If that doesn't work you should try mathstackexange instead.